# Hyper-V failover cluster auto load balancing

Tags: hyper-v, failover, optimization

We have a 2 unit Hyper-V cluster and I was wondering if there is a way to auto load balance the two? If one unit is restarted then I need to manually reassign some of the VMs to the unused hypervisor, not a huge burden but it'd be nice not to have to worry about. We're running a mix of Win7, S2008 and S2012.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make sense. A reboot of one of your Hyper-V hosts should trigger a migration of any clustered VM's on that host to the other Hyper-V host. If the VM's are not clustered then you're seeing the expected behavior. Failover Clustering won't migrate a VM that isn't clustered. If you want those VM's to be migrated then you'll need to cluster them.

Comment: I should clarify, the clustering we have works well and all the clustered VMs migrate as they are supposed to. I.e when V01 fails everything on that machine moves to V02. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to get some of the VMs to automatically migrate back to V01 after it comes online again, rather than them all sitting on V02 until I move them back. Which is what happens at the moment.

Comment: That's a different question then the one you originally asked. You can configure the failback settings in the properties (not the settings) of each VM in Failover Cluster Manager on the Failover tab.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your situation what you want to do is do a `Pause > Drain Roles` and then after you are done with the node (rebooting, etc) and want to "load balance" again you could do a `Resume > Fail Roles Back`

[image: drain roles]

[image: fail roles back]

Answer (score 0):

Just wait. 2019 has that at elast as automatic option. It will only do so when load is high one one unit, but it will then move them around.

Also there you can set preferred nodes, so you can distribute them and they will get back to their default node. Not sure 2016 has that (only use cluster in an experimental 2019 at the moment).